# Сan't execute Oracle procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I created the procedure successfully:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_schema.SDRG (
     ID IN NUMBER,
     COUNTER IN NUMBER
)    IS
   BEGIN
    INSERT INTO newtable_test (ID, COUNTER)
    SELECT doc.ID, doc.TPID
     FROM A.doc;
   END SDRG;
```

But I get an error

> ORA-06550

when calling it in Dbeaver:

begin
SDRG;
end;

Tried different options - doesn't work

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 1):

If you have the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_SCHEMA.newtable_test (
  id      VARCHAR2(20),
  counter NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE A.doc (id, tpid) AS
  SELECT 'abc', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'def', 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Then create the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_SCHEMA.SDRG (
  ID      IN VARCHAR2,
  COUNTER IN NUMBER
)
IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MY_SCHEMA.newtable_test (ID, COUNTER)
    SELECT doc.ID, doc.TPID FROM A.doc;
END SDRG;
/
```

Then you can call it using:

```
BEGIN
  -- The parameters don't do anything and can be random values.
  MY_SCHEMA.SDRG('anything', -42);
END;
/
```

Then, after calling the procedure, the `newtable_test` will contain:

| ID | COUNTER |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 1 |
| abc | 2 |
| def | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ikkcPJnE)